# How to perform spring animation in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, spring, animation, swiftui

I want to apply spring animation to my RectangleView. But I don't know how to start with. Because i am adding animation but it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 250, height: 400, alignment: .center)
            .animation(.spring(response: 0, dampingFraction: 1, blendDuration: 10))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please update your post with your code what you have tried for performing spring animation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems like you are doing nothing with Rectangle after you add animation. You have to add Button, so that clicking on that you can perform any action like this,

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isScaleChange = false
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                .scaleEffect(isScaleChange ? 0.5 : 1)
                .animation(.spring(response: 1, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 100.0))
            Button("Animate") {
                self.isScaleChange.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also change response value to `0` to `1`.